# Install plugin in eclipse with p2 (bash)

Tags: eclipse, bash, eclipse-plugin, p2

I try to install plugins into eclipse. So I read I can use p2. I tryed the followoing:

test.sh

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse \
-data /home/Hans/Documents/workspace \
-nosplash \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars \
-installIUs org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group,\ org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group
```

If I run this bash script I get the following output:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/Hans/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://911.fwk1614238:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://911.fwk1614238:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

If I close eclipse I get the following output:

```
test.sh: line 5: -application: command not found
```

Do I need to install p2 before I can use it?

Regards

Comment: At a guess your continuation lines aren't right in your bash script. Those \ characters must be the very last character on the line.

Comment: @greg-449 Hey, thanks you are right! I'm an idiot:O. One more question. If I want to install the whole web package into eclipse mars. (Tools to help create web applications, including JavaScript, XML, XSL, XSD, HTML, XHTML, CSS, JSP, EJBs, Webservices, JPA tand OSGi Enterprise Applications) Is there an easy way to do this? Or I need to put every single package into the bashfile.

Comment: I don't know much about p2 itself so I can't answer that.